# Xcode C++, Cannot call pointer-returning method from main

Tags: c++, xcode5

I'm trying to implement a `LinkedList` data structure. So I have `main.cpp`, `LinkedListClass.cpp`, and `LinkedListClass.h`

Here's my `LinkedListClass.h`

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedListClass
{
public:
    Node* head;
    LinkedListClass();
    ~LinkedListClass();

    void insert(int value);
    void display();
    Node* ktoLast(Node* head, int k);//<-- this compile fine if I didn't call it from main

private:
    Node* tail;
};
```

I tried to call the `ktoLast(Node* head, int k)` method from main, here's how I did it:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    LinkedListClass* myList = new LinkedListClass();

    myList->insert(3);
    myList->insert(4);
    myList->insert(2);
    myList->insert(7);
    myList->display();

    Node* head = myList->head;
    int k = 3;

    int val = myList->ktoLast(head, k)->data;
    cout << val << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The error message:
[image]

===================UPDATE=========================

The method implementation

```
Node* ktoLast(Node* head, int k)
{
    Node* current = head;
    int length = 0;

    // find the length of the list
    while (current)
    {
        length++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    current = head; // reset back to head
    if (k > length || k < 1) return NULL;

    int count = 0;
    while (length - count != k)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return current;

}
```

Comment: Where is your function definition? Presumably in LinkedListClass.cpp. Is it being compiled and linked?

Comment: @sfjac I've added the method implementation above. Yes, if I didn't call the method from main, the program compiles fine. The errors appear when I called `ktoLast(Node* head, int k)` from main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member function definition needs to be written as

```
Node* LinkedListClass::kToLast(Node* head, int k) { ...
```

What you have above is defining a free function with the same name. Also, if `head` is always the head of the current list (`this`)' it doesn't need to be passed as an argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I overlooked that